# Why is Flutter TextEditingController.text not producing the correct String?

Tags: json, flutter, controller

I have a TextEditing Controller that I want to get the input from and send to my server. When the user selects the Submit button, it calls an async method that gathers the information and sends it to the server. When I attempt to convert the String to Json using Json.encode(), it doesn't update the commas and apostrophes so I'm left with trying to manually update it. Is there a reason the Controller text is not seeing those values?

EDIT:
So in order to better explain my issue, and expose my terrible coding practices, I posted more of the class that I've been having issues with. The issue is inside the "_sendPostToServer()" method where it is calling jsonEncode(String).

The String is merely adding quotations around it and not escaping quotes that are in the text itself. That also seems to be the issue with an apostrophe. To be specific, the following two characters [ " , ' ].

My solution, I was just going to modify the String from the TextField but it's giving me some issues I can't figure out why.

Firstly, it is allowing me to modify the String. I can use a RegExp to take out every letter, every number, modify them and such but when I try to grab the double tick or apostrophe, it says the respective char, isn't that respected char. I used a for-loop, printed every character in the textfield string and tried to match it [.contains('"') | .replaceAll('"', "-")] but it seems to think it doesn't exist.

Next, I tried moving it out of the async function. I thought maybe modifying the value inside the async function may give it erroneous results. That was saying the same thing as my previous solution.

I suppose my first problem is why jsonEncode() does not escape certain chars (such as " or ') but I have digressed from that.

```dart
class PostScreenState extends State<PostScreen> {

  PostScreenState({Key key, @required this.user}) : super();

  final User user;
  bool isLoading = false;

  Future<File> futureImageFile;
  String base64Image = "null";
  String fileName, title, content;

  TextEditingController titleController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController contentController = new TextEditingController();

  @override void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    titleController.dispose();
    contentController.dispose();
  }

  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (isLoading) ?
    _buildCreationProgressIndicator()
    :
    _buildPreCreated();
  }

  _sendPostToServer() async {

    String url = CREATE_POST_URL;
    String jsonPostTitle = jsonEncode(titleController.text);
    String jsonPostContent = jsonEncode(contentController.text);

    Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type":"application/json", "accept":"application/json"};


    Map<String,String> body;
    body = {"body":"{\"method\":\"createPost\",\"params\":{\"title\":" +
      "$jsonPostTitle,\"content\":$jsonPostContent,\"image\":\"$base64Image\"}," +
      "\"id\":3}"};

    headers.addAll(body);

    await post(url, headers: headers); 
  }


  Widget _buildCreationProgressIndicator() {...}

  Widget _buildPreCreated() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
  // Make the first child a row for uploading an image, file or linking websites.
        _buildSelectionDisplay(),
  // The second item a place to hold the title
        _buildTitleInput(),
  // Displays an image, if one is selected
        _displayImage(),
  // Container contains TextField for the content of a post
        _buildContentInput(),
  // This row is a button to submit a post.
        _buildSubmitButton()
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSubmitButton() {
    return  Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: new Text("CREATE POST", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        color: MAIN_COLOR_REDDISH,
        onPressed: () async {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = true;
          });

          // Handles submitting content(title, content and any images etc.) to server for db insertion.
          await _sendPostToServer();

          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });

          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, 
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomePage(user: user)
            )
          );
        },
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50.0, 40.0, 100.0, 0),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContentInput() {...}

  Widget _buildTitleInput() {
    return Container(
      child: new TextField(
        controller: titleController,
        autofocus: true,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        maxLines: 3,
        maxLength: 124,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "POST TITLE...",
          hintStyle: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3.0, 0, 3.0, 0),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSelectionDisplay() {...}

  // Selects an image from the gallery
  _pickImageFromGallery(ImageSource imageSource) {...}

  // Creates a widget that displays the image selected from the user's device
  Widget _displayImage() {...}


}
```

Comment: did you mean comma or double ticks?

Comment: your code should work properly according to your code snippet.if it's not than provide full code so we can find problem

Answer (score 0):

In the case you meant `"`,

The code snipped you provided should work. (I tried it and it works). Check if you are assigning the controller properly to the TextInputField.

In the case you meant `,` (Comma),

You simply have to change `tcText.contains('"').toString()` to `tcText.contains(',').toString()`